# make a input field like multi select option

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an input field where i'm making an array when user type something. I am separating the string to array when user press ','. So if user type: "apple, banana, mango", the array is: ['apple', 'banna', 'mango']. I'm using vuejs 2. The code to generate the array is:

```
<template>
    <input type="text" v-model="labelString" @keyup="addLabels">
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            labelString: '',
            labels: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addLabels() {
            this.labels = this.labelString.split(',');
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Now i want to make the input field as like Tags field of StackOverflow site (when you asked a question, Right above 'Post Your Question' Button ).. when user type a word/words and then press ',' it will separate like this field. Can anyone help me how to do it? Or help me to find a direction. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

`<template>
    <span>{{ labels }}</span><input type="text" v-model="labelString" @keyup.188="addLabels">
</template>`

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
        return {
            labelString: '',
            labels: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addLabels() {
            this.labels.push(this.labelString);
            this.labelString = '';
        },
    }
})
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/qynoa4L8/)

And then then style the `span` with labels to make it look as it's located "inside" `input`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But This is not what i want. I want it string to stay in input field, and i need cross button to remove it. As in Tags labels in Ask Question link of this page.

Comment: I want something like Multi-select boxes (pillbox). Checkout Here https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: If you don't want to develop it from scratch I advice you to use [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) then.